# How to implement touch event functionality in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, touch, multi-touch

I'm using a fragment to display a recyclerview. My goal is to have multitouch functionality so that it is possible to make pinch gestures

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScoreboardFragment"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/scoreboardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

in my fragment class I have the function

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_scoreboard, container, false);
        rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
                System.out.println("TEST");
                return true;

            }
        });
```

Which doesn't ever react. I am also using ItemTouchHelper with simplecallbacks to register clicks on items in the recycler view which works fine and it is also possible to scroll in the list if there's a large number of items. So some touch functionality is there. When I used the onTouchListener in main activity it worked fine but when moving it to the fragment it does not.

I'm not sure if any more information would be relevant, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: use Log.d() instead of System.out.println(). or u can use toast "Toast.makeText(this, "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();"

Comment: I tested that and still, nothing happened